# codeigniter .htaccess in shared hosting (mochahost)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

I want to install codeigniter on '**mydomain.com**', hosting (shared) presents next kind of structure:

- public_html/
  - 404/
  - _private/
  - _vti_bin/
  - cgi-bin/
  - addondomain1.com/
  - addondomain2.com/
  - codeigniter
    - application/
    - system/
  - index.php
  - .htaccess

**index.php** (modified):

```
<?php
...
  $system_path = 'codeigniter/system';
  $application_folder = 'codeigniter/application';
...
```

**.htaccess** (default):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

How can I modify .htaccess to force/apply rewrite condition only when url has '**mydomain.com**'?

Comment: I am noob in .htaccess too.. only because I have not needed more than a little bit so far.  ..but until you find the better answer, perhaps you could stick an overriding .htaccess file in the addondomain directories.. to prevent them from using (override) the rules in your default .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To affect only `mydomain.com`, add a `RewriteCond` that matches it in `%{HTTP_HOST}` before the first `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Apply rewrite only to mydomain.com
# Use [NC] for case-insensitive matching
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you also need to match `www.mydomain.com`, make the condition as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

My htaccess that worked for me in host

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```